# How to replace a button's text with a list item text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like the text on my "Main" button to be replaced by a list 'Item' text that is clicked on within the dropdown menu. The jQuery code I used isn't working. I've tried other alternatives but they're not working either. Is there any way I can fix this? Sorry for the bother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several selectors wrong.

Change this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
    $(".dropbtn:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $(".dropbtn:first-child").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

To this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content a").click(function() {
    $('#mainspan').text($(this).text());
    $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
  });
});
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

```js
/* Main menu drops on click */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
  });
});


/* Code to replace button's text */
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content a").click(function() {
    $('#mainspan').text($(this).text());
    $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-main {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 115px;
  height: 28px;
  border: solid 1px #cebbb1;
  background-color: white;
  color: #897f63;
  margin-left: -5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn.active {
  border: solid 1px #0093dc;
  color: #0093dc;
}

#mainspan {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: solid 1px #cebbb1;
  width: 170px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 1px 14px;
  display: block;
  color: #897f63;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #897f63;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TEXTREPLACE.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="dropdown-main">
    <div class="dropbtn">
      <span id="mainspan">Main</span>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type='text/javascript' src="TEXTREPLACE.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Phew, this was so confusing! Many thanks to you for helping, this solution easily resolved my problem!